# Isolating AJAX dependencies when rendering model dependent templates in Backbone

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm currently working on a web app that uses Backbone for rendering templates based on model data pulled down from a server.  Below is my boilerplate code (in CoffeeScript) for model-based template rendering. My problem is that when server response times are slow, rendering hangs while waiting for AJAX calls (fetch) to finish.

I want most of the template to load with the exception of the parts that need data from the model.fetch() call. My templates depend heavily on model data, so I'd like to know if there's a clean or standard way to untangle the model dependent and independent portions of the template's code to minimize a choppy user experience? One thought I had was to load the model independent portions of the template first, followed by the model dependent ones, but that seems inefficient.

```
model = new Model  # Create model
model.fetch().done ->  # Load model data from server
  view = _.template ViewTemplate,  # Fill template w/ model data
    model: model
  $('#view').html view  # Update DOM w/ newly rendered template
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your views are heavily dependent on model data from server, there isn't really a way to speed up rendering. Although, you can improve the perceived performance of rendering your views.

The way improve the perceived performance is by doing 2 pass rendering. First render the view the cached data that you have and show a small spinner so the user knows you're fetching more. The moment your ajax call completes, just re-render the whole view with your updated data. This seems inefficient at start but it works and covers 90% of the use cases without any performance penalty. If you find that this is a performance problem, optimize it later.

Comment: This is similar to the solution I came up with. I wonder if there's a cleaver way to do partial template rendering where the static parts of the template are rendered before the dynamic parts?

Comment: JST and TPL plugins for RequireJS and Renderer for Marionette are able to precompile templates based on default model data and then update after sync/save.